# Using JayData how do you basic authenticate to OData?

Tags: odata, jaydata

I specified the user and password as directed here http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-1.0.5-is-here-with-authentication-support-and-more 
but I am keep getting 401. Any ideas?

Comment: What technology do you use for server implementation? Like WCF or LightSwitch or JayStorm? With WCF you have to tune IIS for Basic Auth support as well. Please try peeking into the traffic with the network tab of Chrome, and on the OData request you should see an Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture the traffic with fiddler or wireshark? Basic auth does work....

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue. I followed the blog post (http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-1.0.5-is-here-with-authentication-support-and-more) and applied the credentials for basisc auth to the context initialization.

```
var ctx = new NutritionDataService.NutritionDbEntities({
        name: 'oData',
        oDataServiceHost: 'https://localhost:44300/Data.svc',
        user: "usr1", 
        password: "test" 
 });
```

But it seems that no authorization header is set.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F228l.png

I've also tried the approach in this post [Problems with jaydata basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097457/problems-with-jaydata-basic-authentication) with the same result - no authorization header is send.

Does anybody have an idea how to trigger jaydata to send the authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found a solution for my issue above. The problem was a misconfiguration on server side using CORS. In the recorded request (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/F228l.png) Chrome sends a "preflighted request" (HTTP request has the method OPTIONS).

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

I hadn't validate the HTTP attribute 'method' on the server, so my BasicAuth module started the authorization process for every incoming HTTP request and failed    immediately doing the first request ("preflight request") because no authorization header was set.

After revising the validation of the HTTP method everything, works as aspected.

I also had to adjust the web.conf

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="BasicAuthModule" type="NutritionDataService.Auth.BasicAuthModule"/>
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3600" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Accept, MaxDataServiceVersion, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, DataServiceVersion" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Access-Control-Allow-Headers has to obtain every requested header otherwise you will get a 501 response. (in the screenshot above it was 'accept, maxdataserviceversion. dataserviceversion, authorization')